# Display markers on maps using Firebase realtime database

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-maps-markers

I am developing an android application in which I have used Firebase as a backend for authentication and storing data.

I am able to store and retrieve the location from Firebase database, but not able to display the marker on the map.

The code is given below:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback
{


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        //Retrieve data from the firebase

    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference().child("users");

    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            collectLocation((Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue());

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
      });
     }

private void collectLocation(Map<String, Object> users)
    {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : users.entrySet())
        {
            //Get user map
            Map singleUser = (Map) entry.getValue();
            //Get phone field and append to list
            locationData.add((String) singleUser.get("location"));

            count[0]++;

        }

        System.out.println("Location: " + locationData.toString());
        System.out.println("My count is: " + count[0]);


        for(String loc : locationData)
        {
            System.out.println("LocationMMdm" + loc);
            String[] Location = loc.split(",");

            for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
            {
                System.out.println("LOcation " + i + " " + Location[i]);
                if (i==0) {
                    lat = Double.parseDouble(Location[i]);
                }
                if (i==1){
                    log = Double.parseDouble(Location[i]);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("lat: " + lat + " " + "log: " + log);
            //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(loc.)).title("A"));

        }
    }

    private void collectdriverInfo(Map<String, Object> users)
    {

        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : users.entrySet())
        {
            //Get user map
            Map singleUser = (Map) entry.getValue();
            //Get phone field and append to list
            DriverInfo.add((String) singleUser.get("driverInfo"));
        }
        System.out.println("Driver Information: " + DriverInfo.toString());
    }

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
  {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat,log)).title("A"));

   }

}
```

I have stored the latitude and longitude values in `lat` and `log` which are declared globally. But I am not able to access them from `onMapReady` function

Comment: Looks like you're missing a call to `getMapAsync()`

Comment: Also, your data can be retrieved before the map is ready. Move the code that retrieves data from FireBase to the end of your `onMapReady`

Comment: And as a side note, you should respect code conventions (`Location`, starting with a capital L is not a good variable name). It will make your code more readable and easier to debug